# Число после запятой

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

```
var x = 63;
var y = 10;
x / y = 6,3 // как из этого значения вытащить одну цифру после запятой?
```

Как из этого вытащить число 3 (только одну цифру после запятой)?

Comment: А что мешает использовать `x % y` ? Тоже даст 3

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev единственный нормальный ответ

Comment: Если чисто математически требуется ответ '0,3', а не '3', то нужно так:  'x % y / y'

Answer (score 5):

Qwertiy почти прав. Но только спрошено про одну первую цифру

```
var s = (x/y+'').split(".")[1].substr(0,1);
```

Comment: `(x/y+'').split(".")[1][0]` :D

Comment: @Qwertiy точно!   стереотипы :)

Answer (score 2):

Там точка, а не запятая.

```
("" + x/y).split(".")[1]
```

Comment: Зависит от локали, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, это же js, а не java. Не зависит.

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = 63;
const y = 10;
const float = x / y;
const result = float.toString().split('.')[1].charAt(0)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]